# Pandas reshape dataframe where each row is cell value and index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How do I take a normal data frame, like the following:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=['X', 'Y'],index=['A','B'])

    X   Y
A   1   2
B   3   4
```

and produce a new dataframe where each row consists of cell, column name and index, like the following:

```
       col1 col2 col3
row0    1     X    A  
row1    2     Y    A
row2    3     X    B
row3    4     Y    B
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape, then [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for new columns names, [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for `MultiIndex Series` to `DataFrame`, if necessary rename index and change order of columns by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = (df.stack()
        .rename_axis(('col3','col2'))
        .reset_index(name='col1')
        .rename(lambda x: f'row{x}')
        .reindex(['col1','col2','col3'], axis=1))
print (df)
      col1 col2 col3
row0     1    X    A
row1     2    Y    A
row2     3    X    B
row3     4    Y    B
```

Numpy/pandas solution - [`numpy.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html), [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': df.to_numpy().ravel(),
                   'col2': np.tile(df.columns,len(df.index)),
                   'col3': np.repeat(df.index,len(df.columns))}).rename(lambda x: f'row{x}')
print (df)
      col1 col2 col3
row0     1    X    A
row1     2    Y    A
row2     3    X    B
row3     4    Y    B
```